# CSS border and the :hover dynamic pseudo-class

Tags: css, menu, hover, border

I have built a persistent dropline menu with two levels using only CSS. It is pretty standard.

It is a nested set of UL's and the UL's :hover state is what shows and hides the sub menu levels.

Something like this:

```
| *Pets* | Colors | Cars |
| Cats | Dogs | Birds| Goats | Sheep | 


| Pets | *Colors* | Cars |
| Red | Orange | Green | Blue| Yellow |
```

I then added a 1px border at the bottom of the first level UL element. Like this:

```
| *Pets* | Colors | Cars |
--------------------------------------
| Cats | Dogs | Birds| Goats | Sheep |
```

When I hover over a first level item (Pets), and then move the mouse down to the second level (Cats), the entire second level disappears.

I finally figured out that the UL's 1px border is not included in the hover area for the UL.

**Can I add a border to the bottom of a dropline menu level without messing up the menu hovering?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're actually adding the `:hover` state to the `<li>`s within the `<ul>`, the border on the parent `<ul>` isn't included in the `:hover` area.  It would solve your problem to add the border to each `<li>` instead of the parent `<ul>`.  Make sure to add left and right margins of 0 to the `<li>`s and even if you do that you still might need to add a negative left margin or left position to remove any gaps in the border, as well as add override styles to the submenu `<li>`s if they end up with a bottom border as well.

---

EDIT: Ok, I've got a solution that will hopefully work for you, using the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Main1
      <ul><li>sub1</li><li>sub2</li><li>sub3</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main2
      <ul><li>sub1</li><li>sub2</li><li>sub3</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main3
      <ul><li>sub1</li><li>sub2</li><li>sub3</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main4
      <ul><li>sub1</li><li>sub2</li><li>sub3</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this CSS:

```
ul { background:#ccc; border-bottom:5px solid #0c0; height:25px; }
ul li { cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; position:relative; height:30px; 
        zoom:1; _display:inline; }
ul li:hover ul { display:block; }
ul li ul { border:0 none; display:none; position:absolute; top:30px; }
ul li ul li { display:inline; padding:5px; }
```

​
​The key parts here are:

- Set height of `ul` to be smaller than the height of the main `ul li` by an amount equal to the `border-width`
- Set `display:inline-block` on `li` so height attribute takes effect

  - (Note: `zoom:1; _display:inline;` for IE6)
- Set `position:relative` on the main `ul li` and `position:absolute` on the sub 'ul li ul' with 'top' value of the main 'ul li' height

Tested and working: http://jsfiddle.net/TKrSM/1/
(may have to adjust height and top values for padding in your version)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried adding a border to the LI child elements but it raised a few problems. For instance some of the menu levels only have a few items. They are not wide enough to span the entire page width. Any borders on the LI are also not wide enough to span the whole page width.

Comment: One more question. How can I get the sub UL elements to left align with the top level UL? They appear underneath the parent LI that is being hovered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a background and give it a 1px black line at the bottom, or you can add an element and position it absolutely with a 1px height and black background. I would go with the background option, because it´s much easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I had thought about the background image solution too. I hadn't thought of the 1px height absolutely positioned block.